# C# Issues with Task Scheduler library

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have gone every where for this and can not figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am using the `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler` library.  Every time I step through the code, my task is always null.  Here is the code.

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    myConnection2.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp_GetProcessStart", myConnection2);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtTaskID.Text);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string task = rdr["TaskName"].ToString();
            string newName = task.Remove(task.Length - 4, 4);

            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                Task t;
                t = ts.FindTask(newName);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    t.Run();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stored procedure is `SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID`. The table has all of my `ScheduledTasks` with an ID assigned to each.  The table, however, stores them as "Task.job" so I am removing the ".job".  No matter what I do, t is always null and I can figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into FindTask?

Comment: Yes, the name is correct in FindTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  Come to find out I was not pulling in my server variable so it did not know what task to run.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove .job extention. It will find your jobs with .job extention only.

If that doesn't work out try using

```
OpenTask("jobname");
```

Comment: I have tried manually adding the task name and it still will not work.

Comment: are you sure that the task appears in the TaskManager and is not disabled or deleted.

Comment: also with Windows Vista onwards all Operting systems use Task Scheduler 2.0 and it uses a different library.

Comment: This is Server 2003.  Yeah it is definitely not disabled and it exists.